# jQuery - Tremble images on event onClick

Tags: jquery, image, events, animation

I would like that on click on a specific image, it "tremble" for a moment.

This is my code html:

```
<div class="larger" id="miniGallery">

<div class="row spacer buttons-central">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/2.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/3.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
</div>

<div class="row spacer buttons-central">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/4.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/5.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/6.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Is it possible? If yes, the maximum would be a single jQuery function that works for every image of the group miniGallery ID; How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS3:

Example:

html:

```
<div id="shake"> </div>
```

css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shakeelement {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

#shake {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;

}

#shake:ACTIVE
{
    -webkit-animation-name: shakeelement;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Check this code on fiddle to see: `http://jsfiddle.net/jCyD2/`

This example only works in webkit browsers.

Comment: Nothing happens in fiddle,i Am using firefox 24.0

Comment: Try now, i edit to work with Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/jCyD2/1/.  Note that this example does not work in old browsers

Comment: still not working , wait i think it shifted a little on first click

Comment: This code works perfectly on Firefox but doesn't works on Safari (iOS version)

Answer (score 3):

you can try the

## [Shake effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/)

```
$("a img").click(function (e) {
    $(this).effect("shake");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/D4RdB/)

Answer (score 1):

created a quick function http://jsfiddle.net/vZprf/1/

```
function tremble(el, speed, rotations) {
    var i = 4;
    var int = setInterval(function () {
        var isod = i % 2;
        var degree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
        if (isod) degree = degree * (-1);
        if (i == rotations) {
            i = 4;
            clearInterval(int);
            degree = 0;
        } else {

            i++;
        }
        el.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                'zoom': 1
        });
    }, speed);
}

tremble($(el), 50, 40);
```

for your case

```
$("img").click(function(){
    tremble($(this), 50, 40);
});
```

it's used like this

```
    tremble(//element for rotating, //speed at which to rotate, //number of rotations);
```